# JRuby JDBC Without Username or Password in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, odbc, jruby, jdbc-odbc

It it possible to use the JDBC Postgres (jRuby) driver without specifying a username and password in the database.yml file? My project database file currently is:

```
test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 5

development: &development
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 5

production: &production
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_production
  pool: 5

cucumber:
  <<: *test
```

However, this causes the following error on starting the server / console:

> ActiveRecord::JDBCError: The driver encountered an unknown error: FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

If possible, it would be nice to not include the username and password out of the database.yml configuration file (this works with MRI and the `pg` gem). Each team members uses a different username for their local installs.